# NServiceBus 6 with RabbitMQ 3.3.2 as Transport

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I'm trying to use NServiceBus 6 with RabbitMQ 3.3.2 as Transport , when trying to start the end point getting the following exception:

> {AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406,  text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid arg 'x-message-ttl' for  queue 'nsb.delay-level-27' in vhost '/':  {value_too_big,134217728000}", classId=50, methodId=10, cause=}

How do I fix this error message?

Comment: Can you share the log file please?